# Table's last border is hidden

Tags: microsoft-word

If I extend the last side to the right side much, the part (after a specific area as you see on image with red) becomes hidden , probably overflown by white blank space or whatever IDK.

how should i make it to show? (i want full width table):
[image]

p.s. that page is landscaped. The previous page are default (portrait), and as i see, right after the vertical parallel of "portrait page" the area becomes invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the first thing you should do is verify that the full table exists and it's just not displaying because of margin settings.

Word will allow paper width up to 22 inches/ 55.88 centimeters, so working from a copy of the document, change the page size to a custom width and make figure out just how much is overflowing.

With the table width now known, and your page size back to what it should be, and your margins minimized to the greatest extent that your printer will work with you can do one of following:

1. Adjust column widths manually and shrink the down to the point where
   the full table fits within the page margins.
2. Select the full table and then from the Table > Layout contextual
   tab, use the AutoFit menu button (from the Cell Size group) and
   choose the AutoFit Window option. This will allow Word to perform
   the column width adjustment.

From either method you use, work from a copy of the source document.